# how to with input add a text to javascript localstroage html

Tags: javascript

I want to add an item or text to the localstorage of my web page using html input.
now how to add an item or text to the localstorage of my web page using input?
I need JavaScript codes
if you send HTML codes I'm thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) you can use `localStorage.setItem(KEY, VALUE);` to update information.

I would recommand using javascript which would be much easier.

Here is an example : https://codepen.io/renaudc5/pen/abPKdZL

You can then look at the content of the localStorage like this :

- Press F12
- Go to the Application TAB
- Select "Local storage" on the left
- Select the website you're on